# In ionic 1.x, how do i require ion-radio require input?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion radio inside a `ng-repeat` with two options: yes or no.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="form" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <ion-radio name="radio{item.data.id}" ng-model="item.data" ng-require ng-value="'yes'" />Yes</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio name="radio{item.data.id}" ng-model="item.data"  ng-require ng-value="'no'" />No</ion-radio>
        <button type="submit" >Submit</submit>
    </form>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
class Ctrl { 
     constructor() {
        this.data = {};
     }
     submit() {
        if (this.data) {
            formService.update(this.data);
        }
     }
}
```

Using the built-in angular form validators, how do i require ion-radio input ?

I've tried adding the ng-required field but it still allows me to submit

P.s. this is for ionic 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, its not documented anywhere AFAIK. But you can just add `ng-require` to the ion-radios by providing a value.

**Before**

```
<ion-radio ng-require name="radio{item.data.id}" ng-model="item.data" ng-value="'yes'" />Yes</ion-radio>
```

**After**

```
<ion-radio ng-require='true' name="radio{item.data.id}" ng-model="item.data"  ng-value="'yes'" />Yes</ion-radio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

Other way to write this is code your own submit button with ng-click event where you add your own validation.

Comment: This is more tedious. I asked for built in validation.